# Derivate of a template class as template itself

Tags: c++, templates

I have two templates (in one file) and 2 Problems:

```
template <class T>
class element
{
private:
T data;      //are type's of own classes
element<T> * before;
element<T> * after;
public:
element(){ <somestuff> };
void setData(const T &s){ this-> data = data;};
void setBefore(const element<T> * element1) { this-> before = element1;}
//.
//.
//. some more functions
};
```

Now I have a second template list which is a derivative of element:

```
template <class T>
class list: public element<T>
{
private:
  element<T> * current;
public:
  list();
  Add()
  {
     element<T> * element1 = new element<T>; //Attention to this line
                                             //please
  }
  //some more functions
}
```

Its working without problems. My problem is the following. If I create an instance of my list:

```
 list<int*>* s = new list<int*>;
```

I can't choose which Type element is of. But I have to. I can't always make a new List for each new Element. Any solution for this? My mind is little bit stucked at the moment.

Comment: what is the idea behind deriving from `element` and at the same time have a member `element*`? It looks like composition and inheritance is used together ...

Comment: I don't understand why it is working without problems. You have members of type `element *` which should be of type `element<T> *`. Which compiler is it?

Comment: @AmiTavory injected class name.

Comment: @davidhigh I want to create a ringlist where I can control my list over a element itself. So I have access to the data of the elements as well. I'm not sure how it is  right but I saw it this way in a lecture of my prof.

Comment: @Ami Tavory I use g++ .  Of cause you are right. I wrote it wrong here. Will correct it now. Sorry

Comment: `So I have access to the data...` did you consider friend?

Comment: If you want `list<T>` to have access to its base class (`element<T>`) members, put these class members as `protected` instead of `private`.